# Javascript IF/Else and performance

Tags: javascript, performance

Do if/else statements affect performance?

**Edit**: Okay this is ridiculous

Comment: Your fella doesn't know JavaScript? There's no such this as if-then statements. if-else maybe.

Comment: Why not write code in your hand? And that give a shoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your colleague is likely referring to is that in some cases assigning a variable every time is faster than checking some condition and then assigning it.

```
var a = 2;

function slower() {
    if (a !== 0)
        a = 0;
}

function faster() {
    a = 0;
}
```

Really though, it is pretty ridiculous to consider performance impact of a single `if` statement considering how powerful today's computers are.